# Does the new Netflix She-Ra recognize He-Man and Eternia at all?

Tags: continuity, he-man, she-ra

Having seen only season 1 and part of season 2 of *She-Ra and the Princesses of Power,*  I understand that it diverges in some major ways from the original canon.  Up to what I last saw, no mention was made of Adora's family background, or her coming from another planet [Eternia].

Since season 4 is going to start soon, I was curious as to whether any decision was made to include mention of He-Man and Eternia at any point?

I get the feeling they wanted to make this series "distinctly different" from its "parent" series, including making it more female-centric as opposed to making it a "distaff counterpart" to the well known He-Man series. Does that mean she will be a completely separate entity, with *no familial* relation to Prince Adam and the royal family at all?

Comment: I know Netflix is working on a new He-Man show with Kevin Smith and on his podcast "Fatman Beyond" he said the new He-Man would exist completely separate from the Netflix She-Ra. I'd imagine they wouldn't want to confuse people with He-Man references that have nothing to do with the show they're developing.

Comment: @TheIronCheek That by itself is kinda confusing, though. I mean, the worlds were intricately linked up to 2012; how do they intend to account for the separation? and they _already_ mention "Grayskull" in _S&PP;_ how do they intend to account for that?

Comment: I've never seen S&PP but from what I understand, it's a modern re-imagining of the source material. But the new He-Man is a direct sequel to the original show. The 2 Netflix shows are radically different in that fact. If they both were modern re-imaginings or both sequels, a crossover reference would work better.

Comment: @TheIronCheek so the new series will pick up where the 1984 [or 2002] series left off, then? That _still_ means S&PP will likely be outside of that continuity. This is because it's still _open_ for 2002 He-Man to speak of a lost twin sister, and in the 1980s version, her presence is an established _fact._ That being the case, it's unlikely the two Netflix series will be linked then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

I doubt there are specific plans to rewrite her He-Man ties away but they are making a direct point to exclude that part of her past.

In December 2018, Inverse reported there were no plans for a He-Man reference in the show:

> Series producer Noelle Stevenson, however, tells Inverse **she doesn’t have any plans to include Prince Adam of Eternia**.
>
> **“He-Man is not really on the table for this iteration of She-Ra at all,”** Stevenson says.
>
> <sub>[Why He-Man Is "Not on the Table" for Netflix's 'She-Ra' Reboot](https://www.inverse.com/article/52009-she-ra-season-2-he-man-not-gonna-happen)</sub>

### But they're leaving the door open a crack...

Later in the same article:

> The character poses “a challenge” for her modern interpretation of She-Ra’s universe. but Stevenson isn’t ruling him out forever either.
>
> “It would be a challenge, I think, to bring He-Man to life in the present day. Even more so than She-Ra,” Stevenson says. “He’s a very iconic character. It’d be a lot of fun to incorporate him into the world of She-Ra, but I don’t know what my what my approach to that would be.”

Also, after Netflix announced Kevin Smith's He-Man sequel, SYFY reported showrunner Noelle Stevenson's idea for a crossover:

> "I'm going to keep pitching this until it happens," Stevenson began. "So, it's He-Man, and it's this awesome, powerhouse, very anime, cool style. Then She-Ra is all poppy colors, and they're both in their style, and they both come together for a She-Ra/He-Man Christmas Special, and Santa will come, and they'll decorate the tree, and teach Skeletor to love. It's gonna be great."
>
> AJ Michalka, who voices Catra on She-Ra, also added that this was an idea she's already tried to put in Smith's head.
>
> "No joke, I worked with Kevin on The Goldbergs for a couple years, and I shamelessly texted him when it was announced he was doing He-Man," Michalka said. "I was like, 'Hey, Kevin. I hope you're well. I heard you were doing He-Man, and I just wanted to let you know that me and the She-Ra girls are ready for a crossover whenever you are.' And he was like, 'I'm gonna consider this.'"
>
> "Everybody tweet him," Michalka told the crowd. "Kevin reads tweets!"
>
> <sub>[SHE-RA SHOWRUNNER PUSHES FOR HE-MAN CROSSOVER CHRISTMAS SPECIAL AT NYCC](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/she-ra-he-man-crossover-nycc)</sub>